# Flutter search in dropdown of search choices isn't working

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, dropdown

I have a dropdown of the search choices package, in the emulator the search bar works normally, however, when I build the APK I cannot search, I type something and the return is empty in the list. Can someone help me? Follow the code.

I've tried changed flexible for expanded, tried to change some props of dropdown...

```
`Widget _dropLojaChoice(context) {
    var items = lojas
        .map(
          (element) =>
          DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(element.nome), value: element.id),
    )
        .toList();
    return SearchChoices.single(
      items: lojas
          .map(
            (element) =>
            DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(element.nome), value: element.id),
      )
          .toList(),
      value: _loja,
      hint: "Unidades",
      searchHint: "Selecione ou busque",
      searchFn: (String keyword, items) {
        List<int> ret = [];
        if (items != null && keyword.isNotEmpty) {
          keyword.split(" ").forEach((k) {
            int i = 0;
            items.forEach((item) {
              print(item.child);
              if (!ret.contains(i) &&
                  k.isNotEmpty &&
                  (item.child
                      .toString()
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .contains(k.toLowerCase()))) {
                ret.add(i);
              }
              i++;
            });
          });
        }
        if (keyword.isEmpty) {
          ret = Iterable<int>.generate(items.length).toList();
        }
        return (ret);
      },
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          _loja = value;
          //widget.usuario.loja = _loja;
          _waitLJ = false;
          _getNFE();
        });
      },
      isExpanded: false,
    );
  }`

`  _getNFE() async {
    //final cep = widget._
    //searchCepController.text;
    _loading = true;
    //final resultOferta = await OfertaService.getOferta(cep: '1');
    await listanfe(_loja, widget.tipomov).then((resultNFE) {
      setState(() {
        Iterable list = json.decode(resultNFE.body);
        //  print(list);
        nfes = list.map((model) => nfe.fromJson(model)).toList();

        //nfes = json.decode(resultNFE.body);
        _loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
`

`body: Column(
        children: [
          //_dropLoja(context),
          _dropLojaChoice(context),
          Flexible(
            //width: 340,
            // height: 216,
            //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(00.0),
            child: _nfes(context),
          ),
        ],
      ),`
```